# Relation of two particular equations

Tags: inequality

I am trying to find if there exists a relation (> or <) between two equations:

$$X = (I\mathbb{P}-I\mathbb{P}x^{*})+q(I-I\mathbb{P})+(cI-qcI)$$

and

$$X' = (I\mathbb{P}'-I\mathbb{P}'x^{**})+q'(I-I\mathbb{P}')+(c'I-q'c'I)$$

Here are some facts about the variables:

$$I \in \mathbb{R}_{++}$$

$$0 < q < q' < 1$$

$$0 < x^{*} < x^{**} < 1$$

$$0 < \mathbb{P} < \mathbb{P}' < 1$$

$$c,c' \in (0,1)$$

My initial attempt was to treat each equation as $A+B+C$ and $A'+B'+C'$ respectively.

However, comparing $A \stackrel{?}{>} A'$ essentially brings me to: $x-xy \stackrel{?}{>} x'-x'y'$ which I know can be either > or < depending on the specific values.

Trying to instead expand them out is leaving me similarly hopeless. It's entirely possible I can not simply put < or > between the two, but I figured I would reach out here before I accept that fate (I have not been able to produce a counterexample, but perhaps someone else can).

If there exists a relation, my intuition suggests $X' > X$

Answer (score 0):

No, I cannot say > or < here.

Consider:

$$I = 1$$

$$q = 0.5$$

$$x^{*} = 0.5$$

$$\mathbb{P} = 0.5$$

$$c = 0.5$$

Then $X = 0.75$

$$I' = 1$$

$$q' = 0.51$$

$$x^{**} = 0.51$$

$$\mathbb{P}' = 0.51$$

$$c' = 0.01$$

Now, $X' \approx 0.50$

So here $X' < X$

Now, suppose $c' = 0.52$,

Now $X' \approx 0.755$

So, $X' > X$

So one is not less than the other for all possible values of the constants.